# Word for blaming your partner for (you) missing out on something

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for when you are in a relationship with someone and because of it you feel like you missed out on some experiences, so you (blank) your partner? I know there is a specific word for it that I cannot think of. Like you are wondering what could have been, and blame them for your fomo. Not direct blame or regret, but a subconscious scorn towards them for what you missed out on.

Comment: I know what *fomo* stands for, but it's quite possible that some (or many) people wouldn't. You should always spell out things like this.

Comment: @JasonBassford I believe _fomo_ is a recent slang. _fear of missing out_